# How to convert a tweet to image

Tags: image, twitter, converters, tweets

Is there any specific app, website or something that converts tweets into images? I would like to share tweets in other apps like Telegram, whatsapp etc. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a screenshot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google has a [secret screenshot API](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/11/google-secret-screenshot-api/)

For example, you can use it to get a screenshot of a tweet like this

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?screenshot=true&strategy=mobile&url=https%3a%2f%2ftwitter.com%2fedent%2fstatus%2f661570680253755392

At the bottom of that JSON response, you'll see

```
"screenshot": {
     "data": "_9j_4AAQSkZJRgAB.....=",
     "height": 569,
     "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
     "width": 320
 }
```

You will need to Base64 decode it using the [URL and Filename safe alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-8).

That will give you a JPG screenshot of the Tweet.

Answer (score 3):

You can now get images or screenshots of tweets using the @aissistant handle on twitter.

```
Retweet or reply to any tweet with the comment "@aissistant #image" to get an image. 
Retweet or reply to any tweet with the comment "@aissistant #screenshot" to get a screenshot.
Retweet any tweet containing images or videos with the comment "@aissistant #video" to get a video.
```

For other options like converting to memes and jokes check out the handle.

Full disclosure: I am creator of the bot behind the handle.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a small web-app to convert tweets to images. It connects Twitter's embed URL with Puppeteer in the backend and take a screenshot. You can also change some parameters like image width, padding, theme and download the image as a png file.

It's open source so you can take a look at the code.

https://github.com/ozgrozer/tweet-image

https://tweet-image.glitch.me/

[image]